# Setting up an update in a ToDo list app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm working on creating a CRUD todo app using AngularJS, Node, Express, and MongoDB.  I've got all parts figured out except for update part. I'm not really sure how to implement that or what the code might look like.  Particularly the AngularJS stuff (express routing isn't so bad).  I'd like it if I could update by ID.  Was hoping to get some input.

```
function mainController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};

// when landing on the page, get all todos and show them
$http.get('/api/todos')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.todos = data;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });

// when submitting the add form, send the text to the node API
$scope.createTodo = function() {
    $http.post('/api/todos', $scope.formData)
        .success(function(data) {
            $('input').val('');
            $scope.todos = data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};

// delete a todo after checking it
$scope.deleteTodo = function(id) {
    $http.delete('/api/todos/' + id)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

Here are the routes just in case that matters.

```
app.get('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
    // use mongoose to get all todos in the database
    Todo.find(function(err, todos) {

        // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        res.json(todos); // return all todos in JSON format
    });
});

// create todo and send back all todos after creation
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text : req.body.text,
        done : false
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });

});

// delete a todo
app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
    Todo.remove({
        _id : req.params.todo_id
    }, function(err, todo) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});




// application -------------------------------------------------------------
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the page changes on the front-end)
});
};
```

Comment: simply use `$http.put` with appropriate `url` (of the form `/api/todos/' + id`) and in `data` parameter specify your updates.

Comment: So like this? 

$http.put(/api/todos/' + id)
.success(function(data) {
            $scope.todos = data;
        })?

Comment: almost: `$http.put('url', data : {property1:newValue1, ... , propertyN:newValueN}).success(function(data){...}).error(function(err){...})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways - you can use $http.put bu you can also use $resource. I hope that this will help you

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angularjs_app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <form name="todoForm" novalidate>
      <label>Id</label>
      <input type="text" name="_id" ng-model="editTodo._id">
      <br/>    
      <label>Subject</label>
      <input type="text" name="subject" ng-model="editTodo.subject">
      <br/>
      <label>Description</label>
      <input type="text" name="desc" ng-model="editTodo.desc">
      <br/>
      <button ng-click="updateTodo()">Update Todo</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**angularjs_app.js (1 Way)**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.updateTodo = function() {

      $http.put('/api/todos/' + $scope.editTodo._id, $scope.editTodo).success(function() { 
        alert('Todo updated');
      });

      // Or you can try
      // $http.put('/api/todos/' + $scope.editTodo._id, {"todo": $scope.editTodo})
      // .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      //   $scope.editTodo = data.todo;
      // })
      // .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
      //   alert(data.error_message);
      // });

    };
}]);
```

**angularjs_app.js (2 Way)**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'myAppServices']);

myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'TodoFactory',
  function($scope, TodoFactory) {

    $scope.updateTodo = function() {
      TodoFactory.update($scope.editTodo, function() {
        alert('Todo updated');
      });
    };
}]);

var myAppServices = angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource']);

myAppServices.factory('TodoFactory', ['$resource',
  function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/todos/:todoId', {}, {
       update: {method:'PUT', params: {todoId: '@_id'}}
    });
  }
]);
```

**nodejs_server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var todos = require('./routes_todos');

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));  /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/api/todos', todos.findAll);
app.get('/api/todos/:id', todos.findById);
app.post('/api/todos', todos.add);
app.put('/api/todos/:id', todos.update);
app.delete('/api/todos/:id', todos.remove);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

**routes_todos.js**

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Server = mongo.Server;
var Db = mongo.Db;
var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('todosdb', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Connected to 'todosdb' database");
    db.collection('todos', {strict: true}, function(err, collection) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error todos does not exist");
      }
    });
  }
});

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
  db.collection('todos', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
      console.log('todos send from DB');
      res.send(items);
    });
  });
};

exports.findById = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('Retrieving todo: ' + id);
  db.collection('todos', function(err, collection) {
    collection.findOne({'_id': new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
      res.send(item);
    });
  });
};

exports.add = function(req, res) {
  var todo = req.body;
  console.log('Adding todo: ' + JSON.stringify(todo));
  db.collection('todos', function(err, collection) {
    collection.insert(todo, {safe: true}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send({'error': 'An error has occurred'});
      } else {
        console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
        res.send(result[0]);
      }
    });
  });
};

exports.update = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var todo = req.body;
  console.log('Updating todo: ' + id);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(todo));
  delete todo._id;
  db.collection('todos', function(err, collection) {
    collection.update({'_id': new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, todo, {safe: true}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error updating todo: ' + err);
        res.send({'error': 'An error has occurred'});
      } else {
        console.log('' + result + ' document(s) updated');
        res.send(todo);
      }
    });
  });
};

exports.remove = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log('Removing todo: ' + id);
  db.collection('todos', function(err, collection) {
    collection.remove({'_id': new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, {safe: true}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send({'error': 'An error has occurred - ' + err});
      } else {
        console.log('' + result + ' document(s) removed');
        res.send(req.body);
      }
    });
  });
};
```